# How can I add a Unique rule using indicative?

Tags: node.js, validation, adonis.js

I am using Indicative in my project to validate my controller, but, Indicative don't have a "Unique" rule in "Validation Rules", but the framework Adonis have a rule call "unique" that does exactly what i need.

My project is made in Adonis, but i prefer to use "Indicative" and not "Validator" in Adonis, because i think is more easy and beautiful write the code direct in the Controller

```
  code: 'required|string|max:255',
  description: 'required|string|max:255|unique:tabela',
  authors: 'string|max:255',
  status: 'boolean',
  user_id: 'integer',
  created_at: [
    importValidate.validations.dateFormat(['YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'])
  ],
  updated_at: [
    importValidate.validations.dateFormat(['YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'])
  ]
}
```

In the example above, I need the "code" to be "Unique" and return an error message and a response status. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unique` method of `Validator` will automatically search in the database. I don't think it's possible to do it with `Indicative`

I propose this solution (in your **controller**):

```js
const { validate } = use('Validator')

...

const rules = {
    code: 'unique:<table_name>,<field_name>'
}

const messages = {
    'code.unique': '...'
}

const validation = await validate({ code: ... }, rules, messages)

if (validation.fails()) {
    ...
}
```

*To use this command it is necessary to use `Validator`. I don't think there's an equivalent with `Indicative`*

Comment: You can tell me, what happens if i dont set <field_name> in rules?

Comment: You're welcome. In the official documentation this field is not necessary. I think (I haven't tested) that it takes the name of the field in rules (in our case `code`).

Comment: Hello @MauricioCrispim , if this answer answers your question can you validate it (for the next viewers) or can you help me to improve it?